# Why is the ones' complement representation better than others?

Tags: binary, math, ones-complement

It seems like ones' complement representation of signed numbers is the most popular now (and probably the only representation used in the modern hardware). Why is it exactly better than others?

Comment: It isn't. Two's complement is. And wikipedia pretty much sums the advantages up even before the TOC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the dominant representation is two's complement.
Representation methods include:

- sign-magnitude
- ones' complement
- two's complement

Ones' complement replaced sign-magnitude because the circuitry to implement it was much simpler.
Ones' complement has 2 representations for zero which complicates programming since it needs to test for -0 and +0.
This problem is not present in two's complement (has one value for 0) which is the dominant representation used universally today.

Comment: There is also biased representation, as used by the exponent component of IEEE 754 floating point. Also a one's complement system can treat negative zero as a NaN so there is actually one one true zero.

Answer (score 4):

This question starts with a false premise. Two's complement is superior and common. This is because it doesn't have two representations of zero and and the hardware is simpler because the circuity doesn't need to check the sign before performing addition and subtraction.